# How to Prevent Automatic Chapter Creation with \printglossaries

Tags: chapters, glossary

I'm currently working on a thesis using a custom thesis.cls, which is based on the book class. I'm utilizing the [**glossaries package**](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) to generate a glossary with a list of acronyms. However, I'm encountering an issue where every time I use \printglossary, it automatically creates a new chapter for the glossary, which I want to avoid.

I'm looking to insert the glossary in my template:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\chapterheaderpreamble{ACRONYMS AND ABBREVIATIONS}

\vspace{0.3cm}

%Examples
\newacronym{cpu}{CPU}{Central Processing Unit}
\newacronym{ram}{RAM}{Random Access Memory}

\printglossary
```

But this creates

1. A page with the title ACRONYMS AND ABBREVIATIONS without any further text
2. An empty page
3. A new chapter page "GLOSSARY" (in the thesis design)
4. Another empty page
5. The list of acronyms

I'm looking to insert the glossary without it starting a new chapter title and ideally without it starting on a new page. Instead, it should seamlessly integrate into the current section or chapter.

```
\printglossary[type=main, title=, toctitle=]
```

only leaves the Title of the chapter page blank (instead of GLOSSARY).

Here is a simplified excerpt from my full code:

```
\documentclass[english]{thesis}
% Other packages and definitions

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

% Beginning of the document, including TOC and other lists

%%%%%%%%%% GLOSSARY PAGE START

% Attempting to insert the glossary
\thispagestyle{empty}
\chapterheaderpreamble{ACRONYMS AND ABBREVIATIONS}

\vspace{0.3cm}

%Examples
\newacronym{cpu}{CPU}{Central Processing Unit}
\newacronym{ram}{RAM}{Random Access Memory}
\printglossaries

%%%%%%%%%% GLOSSARY PAGE END

\chapter{Introduction}
% Chapter content

% Further content
\end{document}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can prevent \printglossaries from automatically creating a new chapter, or how to insert the glossary in a way that meets my requirements?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to @Dai Bowen for the link. This works:

```
% Acronymes
\usepackage[section=section]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
```